# Azure function An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c#, .net, azure, https, azure-functions

I'm working with an azure function and calling a local API to test my function.

I keep getting this error:

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

The URL I'm trying to call looks something like `https://localhost:xxxxx`

I have seen a lot of other StackOverflow posts such as changing my app service plan and I'm using the standard and still get the same error.

Edit:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
   using (var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:xxxx"))
   {
      string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess, the actual URL of Azure Functions running locally will be `http://localhost:xxxx/api/functionName` - Did you try this?

Comment: the url is not an azure function, but an API on a node server listening to localhost.

Comment: could you provide the code for how you're calling that API on a node server using azure functions?

Comment: I added a snippet to my original post

Answer (score 0):

**One of the workaround I did to call the API from the Azure Function App (.NET 6) is below:**

**Function1.cs:**

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;

namespace KrishNet6FuncHttpTrigger
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "GetServerVariables")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var result = "";
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0014 // Type or member is obsolete
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.sampleapis.com/coffee/hot");
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0014 // Type or member is obsolete
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            //httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer **token**";

            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
             SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                log.LogInformation(result);
            }
            return new OkObjectResult(result);

        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: FunctionRestAPIResult]