# HttpClient Error: `An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permission` from Azure Function Thread

Tags: sockets, azure-functions

I have an Azure function app. I am facing the Socket access permission issue.

**The Issue**:

We face a socket connection issue with the message.  This message came when we execute `HttpClient` to the server. `HttpClient` does not return any other information with error message.

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (xyz.server.com:port)
```

This Issue is not happening every time, it happens randomly for some time of period, and then goes.

**Reason for the Issue**:

We neither have any idea about the cause of the issue nor are sure if the issue occurred at Azure Level due to some network setup or occurred from the server we are trying to connect to via HTTP Client.

Please help us with how we can check the Azure side to identify the issue. We already Informed the Support team of the other server where CRUD operation happens.

**Azure Function App Config**

- Region: US-West 2
- OS: Window
- Function Runtime: 4.15.2.20177
- Mode: Run from Precompiled Package

**App Code Setting**

- Framework: NET 6.0
- C#: 10
- Ready To Run: true

**Network**

- Inbound Access Restriction: Off
- Inbound App Assigned Address: off
- Outbound VNET: N/A
- Outbound Hybrid Connection: N/A
- Outbound NAT Gateway: N/A

*Note*:

This [Stack overflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71164859/azure-function-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its) mentions the same kind of issue. over there one answer suggests using HTTPWebRequest and Response instead of HttpClient.

That I will check in some time if it fixes the issue or not?

**Process detail**:

The Azure Function App is getting called from the scheduler from Our Server every X Min. When it's being executed.

It will check for a particular status let's say `Start a Thread`. The function App will start a new thread and change the status `Thread is Running` and change it again `Thread completed` once the task in the thread is completed.

This Thread created by Function uses `HttpClient` to connect with another server to CRUD operation for different data based on unique identifiers. (No of Identifier need to process will vary from time to time)

Let's say we have to process 200 identifiers. Now Thread is processing all identifiers one by one (we do that as we don't want to overwhelm our server where we doing) Async CRUD operation.

Comment: If another thread has the same issue, and an answer suggests something you haven’t tried, you should follow that answer before making a new question, regardlless of whether you think it will help or how much time it will take.